# Mono throwing warning that I don't think is correct

Tags: c#, mono, compiler-warnings, dmcs

Mono is throwing the warning:

`warning CS0414: The private field 'Convergence.Core.Services.PermissionService.userService' is assigned but its value is never used`

Which is strange, since it is most certainly used:

For instance:

```
var systemRoles = (
    from e 
    in systemRoleRepository.Entities 
    where e.User.Username.Equals(userService.CurrentUser.Username)
    select e
).ToList();
```

(The where clause makes use of userService).

The object is the same object that the compiler is comlaining about, and is declared as:

```
private readonly IUserService userService;
```

To determine that it is in fact being used, if I comment out the declaration, the Mono compiler throws and error on that LINQ query saying userService isn't declared.

Am I missing something really really obvious, or is this a bug in the mono compiler (dmcs on 2.8.1 on RHEL 5.5 by the way).

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug.  Please file it at [Novell's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.novell.com/).

Comment: Thanks - I searched for it in bugzilla prior to posting, but evidently not very well.  Found it as soon as I went to raise the case: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=625583